# No plugin found for prefix '.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp' in the current project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm trying to start my Spring Boot application locally in debugging mode.

I navigate to the directory with my application.
I launch the application and specify the necessary JVM arguments and the debug port using the following command:

- `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8080"`

I get the following error:

`[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix '.jvmArguments=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\flore\.m2\repository), spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot), spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/milestone), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]`

The content of pom.xml file is as it follows:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>me.zhulin</groupId>
        <artifactId>shop-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>shop-api</name>
        <description>Online Shopping API Server</description>
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>11</java.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
                <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1</version>
            </dependency>
    
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>spring-milestones</id>
                <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </project>
```

Comment: if you are using pom.xml, please share

Answer (score 0):

Your command needs modification, actual command would be:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8080"
```

You have to use `-Dspring-boot` before your run.jvmArguments to make is execute.

Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run.examples.debug